# I want to change the distance between my label and the text in enumerate

Tags: enumerate

I want to change the distance between the label and the text. This has to be in all the enumerate environments in my document.

Now I make something like this

```
\documentclass{book}
 \usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[(1)\quad]
\item blabla
\item blabla
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Is their a way to define this for the whole document?

Edit:

This must only be the case with enumerate. Not with itemize. AND the numbering must be (1), (2), ... in the whole document in the enumerate environment.

Comment: Have a look at the `enumitem` package, probably the standard method for dealing with lists these days, and the syntax you show in this MWE is not supported by `book`

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `\setlist` macro from the `enumitem` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{label=(\arabic*), labelsep=1em}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Lorem
    \item Ipsum
    \item Dolor
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image: Enumerate example]

EDIT: You can also customize the format of the links to the items:

```
 \setlist[enumerate]{label=(\arabic*), ref=\arabic*, labelsep=1em}
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @daleif, you can use the `enumitem` package to set the label separation. The following example will give you an idea.

```
\documentclass{article}
%
\usepackage{enumitem}
  \setlength{\labelsep}{2em}

\begin{document}

%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
  \vspace{0pt}
%
\begin{itemize}
  \item blah 
  \item blah 
  \item blah 
  \item blah 
\end{itemize}
%

%
\begin{enumerate}
  \item blah 
  \item blah 
  \item blah 
  \item blah 
\end{enumerate}
%

\end{minipage}
%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
  \vspace{0pt}
  \setlength{\labelsep}{.5em}
%
\begin{enumerate}
  \item more blah 
  \item more blah 
  \item more blah 
  \item more blah 
\end{enumerate}
%
%
\begin{itemize}
  \item more blah 
  \item more blah 
  \item more blah 
  \item more blah 
\end{itemize}
%

\end{minipage}
%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you are not even using `enumitem`'s interface in this example. Use `\setlist` instead of messing with `\setlength`

Comment: thanks. But I only want this in the enumerate. Not in the itemize environment ...

Comment: @ArneTimperman read the `enumitem` manual, hint `\setlist[enumerate]{....}`

Comment: @ArneTimperman, better use the `\setlist` command as suggested, and ignore my reply.

Comment: The external `minipage` environment looks weird, and it does not address the request for `(1)` enumeration at all